# Add quotation marks to comma delimited string in PHP

Tags: php, string, quotation-marks, delimited

I have a form which is a select multiple input which POSTs values like this: `option1,option2,option3` etc..

How is the best way to convert this to `'option1','option2','option3'` etc...

Currenty I'm doing this, but it feels wrong??

```
$variable=explode(",", $variable);
$variable=implode("','", $variable);
```

The reason why I'm doing this is because I want to use the form select multiple inputs in a SQL Query using IN.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE some_column IN ('$variable')
```

Comment: How does that even work out to put the first and the last `'`? Or do you put it in some code you don't show?

Comment: I edited the SQL statement where I added the quotation marks to the variable.

Comment: Don't build up query strings like this. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: meagar, why not? why is PDO better?

Comment: You might be better of with `FIND_IN_SET()` then, escaping-wise.

Comment: Mario, how could I use this? I'm not interested in the position of the value?

Comment: If your csv file has a column with data "Hey, Chuck Norris" and it really meant to be a single cell, your script makes it a mess.

Comment: How are you getting the PHP code to comma-delimit the incoming selected values? What's your HTML?

Answer (score 15):

You can wrap whatever code in a function to make the "feels wrong" feeling disapear. E.g.:

```
function buildSqlInClauseFromCsv($csv)
{
        return "in ('" . str_replace(",", "','", $csv) . "') ";
}
```

Comment: What I mean by "feels wrong" is that there might be a bitter way :)

Do you think this function will do it faster?

Answer (score 4):

If $variable = "option1,option2,option3"

you can use:

"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIND_IN_SET(some_column, '$variable')"

Comment: How to use NOT IN SET?

Comment: Kiran Reddy: SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(some_column, '$variable')

Answer (score 3):

we know that implode converts array to string,we need to provide the separator and then array as shown below, here we have (coma ,) as a separator.
Implode breaks each element of an array with the given separator,I have conceited '(single quotes) with the separator.

```
 $arr = array();
    $arr[] = "raam"; 
    $arr[] = "laxman"; 
    $arr[] = "Bharat"; 
    $arr[] = "Arjun"; 
    $arr[] = "Dhavel"; 
    var_dump($arr);


    $str = "'".implode("','", $arr)."'";
    echo $str;
```

**output:**  'raam','laxman','Bharat','Arjun','Dhavel'

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I used:

```
WHERE  column IN ('".str_replace(",", "','", $_GET[stringlist])."')
```

Comment: Great. why implode explode, if you can do it in one line.

Comment: love it. very simple solution.

Answer (score -1):

There is only one correct way to escape strings for SQL - **use the function provided by the database api to escape strings for SQL**. While `mysyl_*` provides `mysql_real_escape_string()`:

```
$choices = explode(",", $variable);

foreach($choices as &$choice)
    $choice = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($choice)."'";

$choices = implode(",", $choices);
```

PDO provides a method that will add quotes at the same time:

```
$choices = explode(",", $variable);

foreach($choices as &$choice)
    $choice = $pdoDb->quote($choice);

$choices = implode(",", $choices);
```

<sup>Note that PDO::prepare [doesn't really work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition) here</sup>

Comment: that is good practice, but unfortunately is not an answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: @Hammerite: Not recommending - the question implies the asker is already using it.

Comment: @Asad: I was under the impression it added quotes for you. Edited to use the PDO version, which does.